# How to select any random value from a dropdown?

Tags: java, selenium-rc

I am working on selenium using Java. In my application I want to select any random value from the dropdown. Please tell how is it possible?

Comment: with "random" you mean like "I don't care what is selected"? Why don't just pick the first option always?

Answer (score 2):

Well, first get the total number of items in the dropdown. Then generate a random number between 0 and dropdown items count. Then select that number as index to set your dropdown item

Answer (score 2):

Use [getSelectOptions](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getSelectOptions%28java.lang.String%29) to get an array of options of the select box.

Then generate a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and the length of the array (exclusive).

Then use [select](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#select%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with an index locator to select the randomly chosen option.

Answer (score 1):

What Sachin said.
I know often it's good to get an actual code reply, so assuming you're working with a `JComboBox`:

`comboBox.setSelectedIndex(new Random().nextInt(comboBox.getItemCount()));`

The class [Random](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) can be found in the `java.util` package.

Comment: Yes, a code example is good, but sorry, in this case, the user is referencing Selenium, and not swing.

Answer (score 1):

First generate a random number between 0 and the number of items in your list. For example:

```
int random = new Random().nextInt(5);
```

Then use this random number as the index in your [select](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#select%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) call:

```
select("mydropdown", "index=" + random);
```